# How do I iterate through a string array and reset the index back to 0?

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, foreach

```
foreach (string announcements in _message) {
                SendMessage(String.Format("MessageAnnouncer: {0}", _message));
                _waitHandle.WaitOne(messageinterval);
            }
```

I have a string array containing three messages in _message and would like to cycle through these messages. When the index number becomes greater than the array (it runs out of messages) I would like to reset it back to 0 and start the whole process again. How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < _message.Length; i++) {if (someCondition){//do something} else {i = 0}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you hinted at in your question, keep a counter and increment it modulo the number of messages, in the style of:

```
string[] _message = { "a", "b", "c" };
int i = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(_message[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % _message.Length;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
} while (true);
```